# Hidden Step Down Casters

Tags: kitchens, design

I am planning a movable kitchen island and want to hide the casters.

I am planning to use these [stepdown casters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083ND294N).

These caster allow the legs to be lowered down in a stationary position, and when needed lifted up to move the island.

Are there any products available which will hide inside the legs of the kitchen island ?

Comment: From what i can see in the amazon link, each castor has an adjustment wheel. That means that in order to move your cabinet you have to have access to EACH wheel and adjust each one independently. There are commercial and DIY options that let you actuate all four casters with one single foot pedal or other mechanical devise. If you do a search on YouTube you find many DIY options. Also check out place that sell shop equipment  such as Rockler.com  *If you hide those casters you will need a way to access the adjustment wheels*.

Comment: I'm sure you could design a moveable flap or removable door to give you whatever access you need to whatever style of caster you choose. Unfortunately, though, product recommendations are off-topic here.